# jQuery prepending and fading in content does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an ajax form submission system, and I want to prepend the submitted form directly into the HTML when a successful status response is given. Right now I have,

```
$(".post-submit").click(function(){
    var postcontent = $(".post-form").val();

    if (postcontent == ""){
        return false;
    }

    $(".post-form").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/post",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",                    
        data: {"post-form":postcontent},
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var htmlpost = '<div class="post"> <b>${name}</b> </div> \n <p>' + postcontent + '</p> \n';
            $(htmlpost).hide().prependTo(".posts-content").fadeIn("slow");
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Unexpected internal server error. Please try again later.");
         }
    });
});
```

But when I submit a form and get a status 200 back from the server, it doesn't do anything, and the form remains disabled.

Comment: To enable the form, I'm guessing you need `$(".post-form").removeAttr("disabled");` in your success callback, but are you saying none of the code already in your success function works? You're missing the final closing, but that's probably just a typo so i fixed it?

Comment: @adeneo where am I missing a final closing?

Comment: Your example code did, I've edited it?

Comment: Un-asked-for advice: the `<b>` tag stopped being a good practice back in the 90's.  While `<b>` does still work, you'll find a world of formatting options in CSS, and the replacement for `<b>` is just one of them (`<span style='font-weight:bold'>`, or better yet `<span class='bold'>` with a style definition of `.bold{font-weight:bold}`).

Comment: @adeneo Even after changing it, it still will not prepend the html into the body.

Comment: Try sticking an alert or console.log in the success handler to see if it's executed at all.

Comment: @adeneo yes it does execute it all. It's just the prepend statement that is not working. I changed the prepend line to :    $(".posts-content").prepend($("<div>HI</div>").fadeIn("slow"));